# Estoy comenzando a utilizar la API INDEXEDBD, adjunto código y error al final

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

```js
var bd;

function start() {
  zonadatos = document.getElementById("zonadatos");
  boton = document.getElementById("grabar");
  boton.addEventListener("click", agregarobjeto, false);

  var solicitud = indexedDB.open("mibasedos");

  solicitud.onsuccess = function (e) {
    bd = e.target.result;
  };
  
  solicitud.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
    bd = e.target.result;
    bd.createObjectStore("gente", { keyPath: "clave" });
  };
}

function agregarobjeto() {
  var clave = document.getElementById("clave").value;
  var titulo = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  var fecha = document.getElementById("fecha").value;
  var transacion = bd.transaction(["gente"], "readwrite");
  var almacen = transacion.objectStore("gente");
  var agregar = almacen.add({ clave: clave, titulo: titulo, fecha: fecha });
}

window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
```

Error en la anterior línea según consola:

> ERROR:Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on
> 'IDBObjectStore': The object store uses out-of-line keys and has no
> key generator and the key parameter was not provided.
> at HTMLInputElement.agregarobjeto

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor, edita la pregunta para tratar de expresarte con mayor claridad e incluir el mensaje de error completo, junto con el código del método `almacen.add()`

Comment: Hola, perdona, actualice la pregunta , adjunto error justo por detrás de la linea que me marca error la consola de chrome. Saludos

Comment: Eras un problema a la hora de la carga y refrescar el mavegador. gracias